# Cannot import Forecaster from greykite

Tags: python, time-series

I try running this

```
from greykite.framework.templates.forecaster import Forecaster
```

and I get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'statsmodels.compat.python' (/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/compat/python.py)
```

I could not find anything online on how to fix this issue.

Comment: try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHzwaONkqUk&t=12s